# How do I loop after a button is clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I am creating a program at the moment that will have 10 buttons for the user to click: 1 - 10.  The program will tell them if it is divisible by 2 or not.

I'm not completely sure as to how I need to go about this, as I have only started programming in Windows Forms. It probably is really simple but I just can't get my head around it!

I want to be able to read the button clicked... pass it through a loop... then tell the user if the number they click is divisible by two.

I have all the code for this to take work, but it's just the part when the button is clicked, I can't get the number to be passed through the loop to test it. I could copy out all the code for testing under each event field but I have been told I just need to copy it out once. It will mean my code will be much tidier.

Comment: can you post the code currently have?

Comment: What does "read the button clicked... pass it through a loop" mean? There's no "loop" needed to see if a number is divisible by 2, and no "loop" needed to handle a button click. Perhaps if you clarified your question, and provided some code that shows what you've tried that isn't working, we can help you more easily.

Comment: What do you mean by `loop`?

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
//in the form constructor
button1.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
button2.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
button3.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
//and so on
```

Then the method could be like:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   string n = ((Button)sender).Text;
   int number;
   if(int.TryParse(n, out number)){
      if(number % 2 == 0)
         MessageBox.Show(n + "  is divisible by 2");
      else 
         MessageBox.Show(n + "  isn't divisible by 2");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
        void button1_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool result = IsDivisibleByTwo(1);
        }

        void button2_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool result = IsDivisibleByTwo(2);
        }

        bool IsDivisibleByTwo(int x)
        {
            return (x % 2 == 0);
        }
```

Alternatively, you could tag each button with it's value, then get the value from the event sender to pass into the IsDivisble method.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Button1_Click` event you should pull `button1.Text` as the number.  You will need to convert to `int`, via `Convert.ToInt32(button1.Text)`.  It should work as you need from there.